# Cargar scritp de mi pagina en un navegador

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando se carga la pagina, pero no me muestras las graficas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de que se cargan los script si las muestras pero, antes lo tengo que deshabilitar y no quiero hacer eso, pero no se como hacer lo.

Comment: los script que llamas son internos o externos?

Comment: son externios...uso las CDN.

Comment: este problema no es de javascript tu problema es de servidor no tienes instalado el certificado ssl, tu pregunta es muy amplia y engorrosa te propongo explicar un poco mejor y agregar codigo

Comment: Si no poseo eso certificados. Y bueno el código es muy extenso...en local las gráficas se muestran bien, pero en ya en la web que tengo ese problema, lo que no quiere es que los usuarios tenga que estar habilitando los script cada vez que entren a la pagina.

Comment: Ya lo solucione manejare los script de forma local.